# Joomla - count how many times a user have logged in

Tags: joomla

Scenario : my joomla based website have thousands of registered users... on the Administrator back end (in the **User Manager**), I can see the '**Last Visit Date**' for each user.... What if I want to get information on how many times each user have logged in and their visit dates...

Example: User=Mark, Visited site 3 times on 12th Jan, 3rd Feb and 6th Nov 2012...

Comment: download Saxum IP Logger from the Joomla Extensions Directory. This component provides this informations

Answer (score 1):

You would want to make a plugin  that listens for login events.But you'd have to decide how you want to store potentially a lot of data.